# Adding a gradient to tcolorbox colbacktitle

Tags: tcolorbox

I honestly do not know where to begin.

Is it possible, instead of using a single color for the `colbacktitle` to input a gradient?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cover of `tcolorbox` documentation shows an example and the code is just on second page:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
    title style={left color=red, right color=green}, title=This is the title]
    Some text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice suggestion, `+1` just for my clarification, is this possible to give Gradient by using Pantone (spot) colors? Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I've never used pantone colors with LaTeX but I've seen several questions here talking about it. I'm sorry but I don't understand the questions nor the answers so I cannot help you.